# Using postgres currval() in jooq

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am working with postgres database and Java. I am using Jooq to query my database.
 I need to make an insert in my table and get the primary_key/sequence generated by that insert. I know in simple postgres i can do it like this:

This is what my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE "myTable" (

    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "some_text" TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

This is the insert query:

```
INSERT INTO public.myTable(some_text)

VALUES ('myValue');
```

and than to get the latest sequence,

```
SELECT currval('myTableName_myColumnName_seq')

FROM myTable;
```

1) How can I use currval in JOOQ?
Right now I am attempting something like this:

```
config.dsl().insertInto(Tables.myTable)
                .set(Tables.myTable.myText, inputText)
                .execute();

config.dsl().select.currval('myTableName_myColumnName_seq')
                .from myTable;
```

but off-course the last statement gives error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that while you inserting a record to your table, there might be another process that gets value from a sequence and you'll get wrong value with your second query (`SELECT currval`).

PostgreSQL allows you to get some data back in `INSERT` statement with `RETURNING` clause:

```
INSERT INTO public.myTable(some_text)
VALUES ('myValue')
RETURNING id;
```

As jOOQ manual states, you should use `returning` and `fetch` in this case. I'm not sure about proper usage (I'm not familiar with jOOQ), something like following:

```
config.dsl().insertInto(Tables.myTable)
            .set(Tables.myTable.myText, inputText)
            .returning(Tables.myTable.id)
            .fetch();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current value of a sequence through [`Sequence.currval()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Sequence.html#currval--), which returns an expression for that purpose. E.g.

```
dsl().select(MYTABLENAME_MYCOLUMNNAME_SEQ.currval()).from(...)
```

But since this sequence is auto-generated from a `SERIAL` which produces sequence values automatically on your insertions, I completely agree with [icuken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39786901/521799), you should use `INSERT .. RETURNING` instead.

Comment: So i use the above query by icuken and store the result in a Result object. Although i give only one column name in the "returning" function, but i get the whole table with the other columns values marked as null. I now want to extract just the id from this result table. How can i do that? The id is of type Integer in the JOOQ generated class. Its a serial primary key in the database.

Comment: @user1858796: Just use `result.getValue(index, column)`. There are many ways, this is one of them. Hope this helps.